# Set TabIndex to TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, textblock

I'm developing Windows Store application, using C# + XAML.
I have a textblock, used as activation button for HeaderMenu with a chevron character inside it and Tap event binded. How can I activate it by keyboard only?

Should I set TabIndex attribute on it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex on the `<TextBlock... />`

```
<TextBlock Text="Focusable TextBlock"
               Focusable="True"
               KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="4"
               Margin="5"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't set KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex on a TextBlock in Windows Store app. Maybe I need to add some reference?

Comment: Will this link be of use to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.tabindex.aspx or this one: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh868161.aspx

Comment: From what this link states. TextBlock are not UserControls and thus are not able to get the TabIndex property. Don't confuse them with TextBox